# jquery using (this) in custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I created a little jquery script and I have a problem to use (this) in a custom function.

This is the code:

```
jQuery("li").click(function()
{
    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 0)
    {
        jQuery('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function()
        {
            fadeItems();
        });

    }
    else
    {
        fadeItems();    
    }

});

function fadeItems()
{       
    var slogan = jQuery(this).children('p').html();

    jQuery('#slogan_text').fadeOut(150, function(){
        jQuery('#slogan_text').fadeIn(150).html(slogan);
    });

    var content = jQuery(this).children('#post_content_large').html();
    jQuery('#content_view').html(content).hide();

    var status = jQuery("#readMore").html();

    if(status == 'Verbergen')
    {
        jQuery('#content_view').fadeIn(500, function(){
            jQuery('#content_view').fadeIn(500).html(content);
        });
    }

    var title = jQuery(this).children('h3').html();

    jQuery('#title_content').fadeOut(150, function(){
        jQuery('#title_content').fadeIn(150).html(title);
    });
}
```

So the function runs when clicking on a list items and that goes wel but the values of (this) is empty

Somebody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.call` can be useful here:

```
jQuery("li").click(function () {
    var self = this;
    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 0) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            fadeItems.call(self);
        });    
    }
    else {
        fadeItems.call(self);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you must pass it to the function so that it can use it (also maybe use domething different from this, is less confusing (EDITED since you want the clicked item)

```
    var clicked = this;
    jQuery('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function()
    {
        fadeItems(clicked);
    });

function fadeItems(el)
{       
var slogan = jQuery(el).children('p').html();
```

Comment: `this` in that case is not the element he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

`fadeItems.apply(this);`

That way you can specify the context for the function call (manually assigning the value of `this` in `fadeItems`)

EDIT: as noted by @KevinB, you will need to alias `this` in the parent function: `var that = this;`, and then pass `that` into the function, `fadeItems.apply(that);`.

Comment: That works great in the `else {}`, but within the animate `this` refers to the `html` and `body` elements

Comment: Ah, good catch. Principle is the same, but you need to store the context in the parent scope.